# interactive container + daemon process at container startup

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create a interactive container but also with a daemon running on the background.

I have built an image with an ENTRYPOINT (Dockerfile: ENTRYPOINT ["service", "mysql", "start"]) and through this image, I have created a interactive container, but the container just doesn't start..

```
    $ docker create --net=host --name=debian-mysql -it ivanlmj/debian-7-mysql-5.7.12:latest bash
    a66630403170f87ca7760a4609675708fa98abfe7e2b7b53a76a147f626aa733

    $ docker ps --all -f "name=debian-mysql"
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
    a66630403170        ivanlmj/debian-7-mysql-5.7.12:latest   "service mysql start   14 seconds ago                                              debian-mysql        

    $ docker start debian-mysql
    debian-mysql

    $ docker ps --all -f "name=debian-mysql"
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                              PORTS               NAMES
    a66630403170        ivanlmj/debian-7-mysql-5.7.12:latest   "service mysql start   27 seconds ago      Exited (0) Less than a second ago                       debian-mysql
```

What is the right way of building an interactive container which also has a daemon running automatically in the background?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After striving for hours and hours, I found it!

Inside the Dockerfile:

```
 
    FROM debian:jessie
    MAINTAINER Ivan Leon (ivanlmj@gmail.com) - @ivanleoncz
    RUN ...
    ...
    ...

    CMD service mysql start && bash
```

- This ultimate statement, will start MySQL via Sys V init script or Upstart.
- If the daemon startup succeeds (bitwise AND: &&), afterwards, a BASH prompt will be spawned.
- When creating a container from the image, just need to specify "-it" for am interactive container, without passing "bash" as command.

  ```
  docker run --net=host --name=debian-mysql -it ivanlmj/debian-7-mysql-5.7.12
  ```

And DONE!

**Important Information**

```
CMD has two forms: with shell and without shell (JSON Array).

If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the  will execute 
in "/bin/sh -c" (it is the default Docker ENTRYPOINT).
```

**Important Reference:** https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd